# What's "neutral space"?

Tags: master-of-orion-2016

I noticed that combat between ships is possible without descending to a state of war. There seems to be some neutral space in which combat is semi-permitted, as this screenshot also demonstrates:

[image: "you engaged in combat with their fleets on neutral space"]

What is this neutral space? Is it systems with no colonies?

Comment: Probably any system that isn't owned by you, them, your allies or their allies. That would include unowned systems and systems owned by third parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unsettled systems are considered neutral.**

Performing combat in one of these areas (such as killing a scout ship) is not as deter-mental as an attack on their system. It also doesn't automatically trigger a declaration of war.

Any system without a planet (such as a wormhole) will always be considered neutral.